# php - Repositories - how should I implement "custom" criteria?

Tags: php, repository-pattern

I'm beginning to learn DDD, etc. Now I have come to the Repository, but I'm not quite sure how I should solve the following issue:
This is my example interface:

```
interface RepositoryInterface {

    public function all($columns = array('*'));

    public function paginate($perPage = 15, $columns = array('*'));

    public function create(array $data);

    public function update(array $data, $id);

    public function delete($id);

    public function find($id, $columns = array('*'));

    public function findBy($field, $value, $columns = array('*'));
}
```

Now I need to retrieve the data for the individual criterion for the model, eg. `findActive` - how should I handle this case? Add such a method to the interface or can refer to any of the above methods and respectively "extend"?

Comment: Rule of thumb is your repository class will only store methods that would start with find.  If it doesn't make sense with, "find", in front of it won't make cents. :--)

Answer (score 2):

For me the findActive() method is more table (model) specific and could be defined in a extra Interface (e.g. CustomerRepositoryInterface). Then you can "implement" these different interfaces in a special class (e.g. CustomerRepository).

Here is an example:

```
<?php

interface RepositoryInterface
{
    public function all($columns = array('*'));
    public function paginate($perPage = 15, $columns = array('*'));
    public function create(array $data);
    public function update(array $data, $id);
    public function delete($id);
    public function find($id, $columns = array('*'));
    public function findBy($field, $value, $columns = array('*'));
}

interface CustomerRepositoryInterface extends RepositoryInterface
{
    public function findActive();
}

abstract class BaseRepository implements RepositoryInterface
{
    public function all($columns = array('*')) {}
    public function paginate($perPage = 15, $columns = array('*'))  {}
    public function create(array $data)  {}
    public function update(array $data, $id) {}
    public function delete($id)  {}
    public function find($id, $columns = array('*'))  {}
    public function findBy($field, $value, $columns = array('*'))  {}
}

class CustomerRepository extends BaseRepository implements CustomerRepositoryInterface
{
    public function findActive()  {
        echo "findActive";
    }
}

$customerRepository = new CustomerRepository();
$customerRepository->findActive();
```

Comment: Looks great! Let me ask one question by the way - how to handle the relationship? In the same way as your example, is it possible to apply a link between particular repositories for specific models?

Comment: In theory a repository knows nothing about other repositories. To handle multiple repositories I would use a service class with all the related repositories as dependency. But in real life you have very complex database queries with multiple tables. In this case I just use a query builder within my "find*()" method and just join the required tables. The result is still a "collection" of data (rows). The relation is defined with the joined tables and the foreign keys.